# Get the total amount price from gridview rows

Tags: c#

Am having a gridview (C#) ,which contains product name,product price,product code...... At the time of page load i need to get the sum of n rows product price to a label... (no sql database here)... Could any one help me out....

Thank you...

Answer (score 3):

You have to loop through the rows and sum it up. Something like the following:

```
double Total = 0;
foreach(GridViewRow row in MyGridView.Rows)
    Total += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[PRICE_COLUMN].Text);
```